# Clustered Regions by Each Neuron in Self Organizing Map (SOM)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, artificial-intelligence

I was given a question about SOM.

There is a SOM which have 4x4 neurons and each neuron's x1 and x2 values (coordinates) given. Also neighborhood function and weight update rule given. How can i find and show the regions which are clustered by each neuron?

Thanks for answers.

Regards...